# Authentication Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an internal app for our support group. We don't have iPhone specific authentication APIs yet. So here's what I'm trying to do. We have an external support portal which, when you attempt to access, redirects to our single sign-on page. The single sign-on page has a form with the regular username, password fields and some hidden input fields. The values of the hidden input fields change regularly.

E.g.:

```xml
<form method="post" action="/server/sso_auth" name="MLoginForm" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="v1.4" />
<input type="hidden" name="auth_id" value="5206764149601646385" />
<input type="hidden" name="AUTH_REQ" value="<value>" />
<input type="hidden" name="sitetoken" value="<value>" />

<input type="text" id="Mssousername" name="ssousername" title=" Please enter a Username" maxlength="80" value="" class="Msf-txtbox" tabindex=2/>

<input type="password" id="Mssopassword" name="password" title=" Please enter a Password" value="" maxlength="255" class="Msf-pwdbox" tabindex=3/>
```

I am able to successfully sign in to the app only if I provide the auth_id, AUTH_REQ and sitetoken fields (using standard NSMutableRequest/NSURLResponse).

Until we have an iPhone specific authentication APIs, I want to be able to read/parse the single sign-on page, read the values of the hidden input fields and use them for authentication.

Right now I am having to first read them off of the browser, copy and paste them into my code and sign in on a daily basis.

Any way I can read those input values directly? Attempting to go to the single sign on page directly is prohibited... It only works on redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Read the page directly with `NSURLConnection`, redirects can be done.  302 redirects can be made to occur automatically, META and Reload redirects have to be done in code with a little parsing.  Javascript call backs can be more problematic.  You can also specify the User Agent to match what the server needs.  I do this all the time.

To handle redirects you can use the `NSURLConnection` callback:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)callbackRequest redirectResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```